# Find and delete duplicate termn in line?

Tags: notepad++

i have a file that duplicates the same term starts with "0/0 ***ends jpg" I want to execute a command and delete one term.

```
<h2>
            3. USS Midway Museum
        </h2>
            "0/0.003.jpg"   "0/0.003.jpg"    
            : meunierd / shutterstock
            USS Midway Museum
            The longest-serving aircraft carrier in the world has been permanently moored at San Diego’s Embarcadero since 2004. Commissioned in 1945, the USS Midway served in the Vietnam War and Operation Desert Storm, before becoming the largest museum dedicated to aircraft carriers and naval aviation anywhere.
            GetYourGuide.com offers a    >self-guided audio tour of this humungous vessel, during which you’ll see over 30 restored aircraft, including 8 propeller planes, 14 jet aircraft and 8 helicopters.
            You’ll be led through the galley, brig, crew’s sleeping quarters, pilots’ ready rooms and engine room, and hear exciting snippets from people who served aboard the Midway.
            You’ll have lots of chances to get involved, testing simulators, climbing into cockpits and watching films documenting the dramatic events that took place where you stand.
        <h2>
            4. Point Loma
        </h2>
            "0/0.004.jpg"   "0/0.004.jpg"    
            : S.Borisov / shutterstock
            Point Loma Lighthouse
            The west side of San Diego Bay is embraced by a long rocky peninsula that merits a visit for jagged topography, thrilling history and views you won’t soon forget.
            We’ll touch on a few of the sights on Point Loma later, but in 1542, this was the landing point for the first European expedition to what is now the West Coast of America.
            Given the peninsula’s setting, protecting the west flank of the harbour, Point Loma has a military presence going back to the 19th century.
            The 77.5-acre Fort Rosecrans National Cemetery (1882) is on the grounds of a former coastal artillery station.
            There are more than 100,000 graves here, and solemn memorials like the USS Bennington Monument, recording an accident in San Diego Bay that claimed 66 lives in 1905. Head to the marina for whale watching expeditions, and to Osprey Point were climbers scale the rocks and fishers camp over the water.
            Available tour:    >GPS Talking Tour Cars: Point Loma &amp; Beaches Loop
        <h2>
            5. La Jolla
        </h2>
            "0/0.005.jpg"   "0/0.005.jpg"    
            : Dancestrokes / shutterstock
```

Comment: can write a program to do that... or i guess regex search would help..

Answer (score 0):

A regex replace is possible using Notepad++.
Something like this should do the trick:

Search:

```
("[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.jpg")\s+\1
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

Which means: find an instance of at least one digit, followed by a slash, followed by a one or more digits, followed by a litteral dot (.), followed by a one or more digits, followed by a litteral dot (.), then 'jpg'. Capture this expression (that's what the parentheses do). This expression should be followed by some whitespace (at least one empty space), and repeat itself once on the same line.
Note that the dot (.) being a special character in regular expression just like the slash (/), it is escaped with a backslash ().

`\1` represents the expression being captured

Thus,

```
"0/0.003.jpg"   "0/0.003.jpg"
```

is replaced to:

```
"0/0.003.jpg"
```

This is meant as an example and can be made stricter and improved. This regex will actually leave some whitespace that is probably unwanted, although it won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `("0/0.*?\.jpg")\h+\1`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(           # start group 1
    "0/0    # literally
    .*?     # 0 or more any charactr but newline
    \.jpg"  # literally
)           # end group 1
\h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
\1          # backreference to group 1
```

---

#### I've simplified the text, keep only the relevant part.

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]